# ordering select box list alphabetically rails 4.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am fetching all currencies for all countries. how can i order them in alphabetical order

here is what i have

```
= f.select :budget_currency, ['None'] + Country.pluck(:currency).compact.uniq.select {|x| x.present?}, {}, :class => "itineraryBudget"
```

Comment: What is that you want to sort countries or currencies or both together?

Comment: To sort an array in an alphabetical order one uses `Array#sort`.